# Template Error -- C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am getting an error ("*default template arguments are only allowed on a class template*") when I use my template in the following way. I have included the template declaration for the class, as well as one of the functions.

```
template<typename K, typename T, bool RINSERT = true>
class BST
{
public:
BST();
.
.
.
```

... and so on. Heres a function that uses these paramters:

```
template<typename K, typename T, bool RINSERT = true>
int BST<K,T,RINSERT>::size() const {
return nodes;
}
```

Am i declaring the function incorrectly?

Comment: Why don't you declare it inline? A lot less to write.

Comment: could you further explain that? ive never actually used inline

Comment: @jordpw - he's suggesting to write the method within your class declaration:  
`...BST();
int size() const { .... }` - however, this can get messy and doesn't really answer your question - @Mike Seymour already pointed out your error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've already declared the default argument on the class template; don't redeclare it on the member definition:

```
template<typename K, typename T, bool RINSERT>
int BST<K,T,RINSERT>::size() const {
    return nodes;
}
```